# Upon publishing to windows azure, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure

Using my old computer. I used to publish web sites to windows azure (that was before the latest azure design) via Visual Studio 2013:

1. Right-click the project
2. Select Publish
3. Select Profile
4. Enter credentials
5. Validate connection
6. Publish

Now (with the latest azure design, and I am now using VS2015), with my new computer. I downloaded the profile I used to have then imported it then published it.

But then I got this error message [image]

Then I tried to debug the error:

I used the connection string from my old published profile then pasted it in my webconfig. Upon running the application, it does not break the application instead it showed the error above.

Basically, I want to use the old profile I used to publish on windows azure. Same domain name and same database (I also want to keep the data)

What options do I have?

PS. I'm still new to windows azure. All I know is publishing website via Visual Studio

**EDIT:** I don't have any error locally

Comment: edit in your web.config file  and set `customerror  mode="false"`

Comment: check your connectionstring. It may happen that system is not able to find an instance of your database.

Comment: try using the published application in your local IIS.

Comment: 1. I tried looking for `customerror` but can't find anything. 2. The connectionstring I used was the one I copied from the azure website. 3. How do I achieve that?

Comment: use your published application in your local System IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the issue at hand, You can enable Diagnostics Logs and Check them to see why your site is crashing. You can even do remote debugging by attaching to the website running on the cloud.

**To get the diagnostics logs follow the below steps.**

1. Go to portal.azure.com.
2. Browse to your web app
3. Open the Settings Blade and Click on the Diagnostics Logs Settings.
4. Set the Diagnostics Settings as below.
   [image]
5. After this go to the Tools by Clicking on Tools Command on the Web App Blade.
   [image]
6. Click on Streaming Logs to see logs coming in at real time.
   [image]
7. If you need to see the logs dumps, You can download the Publishing Profile and access the file share directly using any FTP Client like Filezilla using the FTP UserId and Pwd from the .publish file when you open it with notepad.

**The other way to debug you app is to attach your visual studio directly to the Web App running on the cloud, This is very simple and powerful way to debug the issue interactively, As your error is a null ref the exception will break directly on VS and you should be able to see the cause quickly.**

[Great Blogs on Attaching to VS for a Web App Here.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/)

There are multiple ways to publish your site to Azure Web App.

1. Using Continuous Deployment feature to deploy your bits based on your repo updates. [Great Blog to learn how to setup Continuous Deployment on Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/).
2. Publishing directly from Visual Studio which you are already familiar.Publishing Profile which you can download from the Web App Blade can be used in Web Matrix and other tools to deploy your site directly into a web app.
3. Downloading the Publishing Profile and directly placing the files in to the wwwroot of your website using FTP.

Glad to see developers starting into our product, hope this information helps you get started !.